# Postgresql - avoiding alias for subquery

Tags: postgresql, subquery

Is there maybe a plugin or option for Postgresql which allows to omit the alias for subqueries?

For example, I have to write a query like this:

```
select * from filelist2 
where md5sum in(
select md5sum from(
select md5sum, count(md5sum) from filelist2 
group by md5sum
having count(md5sum)>1) as MANDATORY_ALIAS)
order by md5sum;
```

Without the alias, I get following error:

```
ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias
SQL Status:42601
```

I find that extremely annoying and would like to omit it, like in most other databases.

Comment: most other databases requires it too isnt it..

Comment: No, you can not leave it out.

Comment: but ... why do you care?

Comment: i find it annoying and inconvenient

Comment: AND i have to rewrite most of my queries when trying to migrate from Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an alias in this query, drop the subselect:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  filelist2 
WHERE md5sum IN(
    SELECT md5sum
    FROM filelist2 
    GROUP BY md5sum
    HAVING COUNT(md5sum) > 1
    )
ORDER BY 
    md5sum ASC;
```

Comment: Well, that is avoiding it by rewriting the query in order to avoid the sub-select. I am looking for an option to omit it when using sub-selects.

Comment: If you really need a subquery, you must use an alias.